# How to mix two result set of LEFT JOIN with a key together?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 table with relationship as:  
1. Table S, key name =  SO_ID,    
2. Table D, key name =  DO_ID, foreign key SO_ID. Relationship S-D is 1-N  
3. Table P, key name = MO_ID, foreign key SO-ID. Relationship S-P is 1-M  
4. value of **_ID is about integer.

How I query and get result as:  all data of S with D, and P is present

```
SO-ID   ||    DO_ID      || MO_ID   
1       ||      1        ||    1    
2       ||      ..       ||    ..   
..      ||      N        ||    ..   
..      ||   [blank]     ||    ..   
X       ||   [blank]     ||    ..   
X       ||   [blank]     ||    M
```

Comment: why dont you first study about  left join itself?

Answer (score 0):

**You should study and try by yourself first:**

Please find below query as you asked for

```
select * 
from S s left join
     D d
     on (s.SO_ID = d.SO_ID) left join
     P p
     on (s.SO_ID = p.SO_ID)
```

Comment: Problems is I need to present result as:
- If 1 row from S have n rows in in D and m row in P. I want to present as sample data, that list S - n D -  mP and go on.

Comment: why dont you use order by clause ?